# Как получить доступ к хосту WSL2 из Windows?

Tags: windows, frontend, devops, wsl2

Раскатил проект docker на ubuntu wsl, и есть условный роут http://route-example-name.ru
по которому надо обращаться , чтобы получить страницу сайта,однако, если прописывать этот хост в браузере на windows - ничего не выводит, однако, если в терминале убунуту прописать ping http://route-example-name.ru - всё получается и отдает респонсы

как фиксить, подскажите пожалуйста?

wsl 2

Comment: Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло